# unable to recognize file type

Tags: java, parsing, apache-camel, fileparsing

this is my first post. I'm new in Java. I'm working on file parser. I've tried to identify if it is CSV or another file format, but it looks like it is not quite a standard format. I'm working on apache camel solution (my first and last idea :( ), but maybe some of you recognize this kind of file format? Additionally, I've got .imp file for my output.

Here is my example input:

`NrDok:FS-2222/17/W
Data:12.02.2017
SposobPlatn:GOT
NazwaWystawcy:MAAKAI Gawron
AdresWystawcy:33-123 bABA
KodWystawcy:33-112
MiastoWystawcy:bABA
UlicaWystawcy:czysfa 8
NIPWystawcy:123-19-85-123
NazwaOdbiorcy:abc abc-HANDLOWO-USŁUGOWE
AdresOdbiorcy:33-123 fghd
KodOdbiorcy:33-123
MiastoOdbiorcy:Tdsfs
UlicaOdbiorcy:dfdfdA 39
NIPOdbiorcy:82334349
TelefonOdbiorcy:654-522-124
NrOdbiorcyWSieciSklepow:efdsS-sffgsA
IloscLinii:1
Linia:Nazwa{ĆWIARTKA  KG}Kod{C1}Vat{5}Jm{kg.}Asortyment{dfgv}Sww{}PKWIU{10.12.10}Ilosc{3.40}Cena{n3.21}Wartosc{n11.83}IleWOpak{1}CenaSp{b0.00}
DoZaplaty:252.32`

And here is my example output file:

`FH 2015.07.31  2015.07.31  F04443  Gotowka 
FO  812-123-45-11   P.a.b.Uc"fdad" abcd deffF   UL.fdfgdfdA 12/33   33-123  afvdf
FS  779-19-06-082   badfdf S.A. ul. Wisniowa 89 60-003  Poznan
FP  00218746    CHRZAN TARTY EXTRA POLONAISE 180G   SZT 32.00   2.21     8  10.39.17.0  32.00   5900138000055`

Is there any easy way to convert the first file to second file format? Maybe you know the type of this file? In a meanwhile, I'm continuing my work with apache camel.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to play with https://tika.apache.org/1.1/detection.html#Mime_Magic_Detection

It's very good lib for file type recognition.

Here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_document_type_detection.htm we have simple example.

Comment: No problem, if it was helpful for you, please vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Your file can be read as standard Java [`.properties`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) file. This type of files allows both `=` and `:` as key and value separators. While the fact that it contains non ISO-8859-1 characters like Polish `Ć` may prevent Java from correctly parsing it.

This line

```
Nazwa{ĆWIARTKA  KG}Kod{C1}Vat{5}Jm{kg.}Asortyment{dfgv}Sww{}PKWIU{10.12.10}Ilosc{3.40}Cena{n3.21}Wartosc{n11.83}IleWOpak{1}CenaSp{b0.00}
```

Seem to be some custom serialization format of the object in the form

```
key1{value1}key2{value2}...
```

Your output file contains lots of data that is not listed in the input which makes me think that there is some data querying from external systems to build the output. You should investigate it yourself. There is no way anyone can *guess* the transformation with provided input.